# Stored Procedure Fill Variable with a ResultSet of a Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a little Problem but don't know the Solution!

I have wrote a Stored Procedure. The function of this isn't necessary.

I want to declare a Variable from Type int.

This Variable must get the Value of a SQL Query.

My attempt:

```
DECLARE @ParentServiceProviderId int = null     
SET @ParentServiceProviderId  = (SELECT ParentServiceProviderId 
                                 FROM ServiceProvider
                                 WHERE ServiceProviderId = @ServiceProviderId)
```

It didn't work! The ResultSet of the Query have one Row every Time!

I don't know how to solve this Problem!

Here is the complete Stored Procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertCarmakerPartnership_ChildToParent]

    @ServiceProviderId int,
    @CarmakerId int,
    @ValidFrom datetime,
    @ValidTo datetime
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @parentSPPId int, @parentSPPParentId int, @superParentId int, @ParentServiceProviderId int = null       

    SET @ParentServiceProviderId  = (SELECT ParentServiceProviderId 
                                     FROM ServiceProvider
                                     WHERE ServiceProviderId = @ServiceProviderId)      

    DECLARE ServiceProviderParent_Cursor CURSOR FOR

    SELECT ServiceProviderId, ParentServiceProviderId
    FROM ServiceProvider 
    WHERE ServiceProviderId = @ParentServiceProviderId

    OPEN ServiceProviderParent_Cursor;

    FETCH NEXT FROM ServiceProviderParent_Cursor INTO @parentSPPId, @parentSPPParentId 

    IF (@ParentServiceProviderId is NULL)
    BEGIN
        SET @superParentId = @ServiceProviderId
        EXEC InsertCarmakerPartnership_ParentToChild @superParentId, @CarmakerId, @ValidFrom, @ValidTo;
    END

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    IF @ServiceProviderId > 0
    BEGIN
        EXEC InsertCarmakerPartnership_ChildToParent @parentSPPId, @CarmakerId, @parentSPPParentId, @ValidFrom, @ValidTo  ;

        IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.CarmakerPartnership WHERE ServiceProviderId = @parentSPPId AND CarmakerId = @CarmakerId AND IsDeleted = 0) = 0
        BEGIN                           
            INSERT INTO dbo.CarmakerPartnership (CarmakerId, ServiceProviderId, CreatedBy, ChangedBy, ValidityPeriodFrom, ValidityPeriodTo) VALUES (@CarmakerId, @parentSPPId, SYSTEM_USER, SYSTEM_USER, @ValidFrom, @ValidTo)
        END             
    END 
    FETCH NEXT FROM ServiceProviderParent_Cursor INTO @parentSPPId, @parentSPPParentId 
END;
    CLOSE ServiceProviderParent_Cursor;
    DEALLOCATE ServiceProviderParent_Cursor;
END
```

Thanks for your help and sorry for my bad english!

Best regards.

Comment: `It didn't work! The ResultSet of the Query have one Row every Time!` - I'm not sure I understand the problem here. Do you expect it sometimes to return more than one row? Or should it be no rows? Or do you mean to say that it always returns the same value? Please clarify this bit. If possible, please use some examples for better illustration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anyway, use next code to populate a variable:

```
DECLARE @ParentServiceProviderId int

SELECT @ParentServiceProviderId = ParentServiceProviderId 
FROM ServiceProvider
WHERE ServiceProviderId = @ServiceProviderId
```

Answer (score 0):

do not assign default value to this variable and the rest of the code is:

```
DECLARE @ParentServiceProviderId int

SELECT @ParentServiceProviderId = ParentServiceProviderId 
                                FROM ServiceProvider
                                WHERE ServiceProviderId = @ServiceProviderId
```